# react-bootstrap How Do You Split A Dropdown.Item?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, drop-down-menu, dropdown, react-bootstrap

I am using [`react-bootstrap`](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/) to create a dropdown menu using the `Dropdown` component.

Although I can get the dropdown to easily work, I want to further split one of the options to be a Split button.

Here is the working code before I attempt to split anything...

```
<DropdownButton 
    variant="light" 
    title={ <><MdFilterListAlt />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span className="text-muted">Filters</span></> }
    >
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">My Invoices</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">Draft</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">Posted</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="4">Cancelled</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="5">To Check</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="6">Unpaid</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="7">Paid</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="8">Overdue</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="9">Invoice Date</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="10">Due Date</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="11">Add Custom Filter</Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>
```

Here is my code (not working but I am trying to illustrate the concept better ):

```
<DropdownButton 
    variant="light" 
    title={ <><MdFilterListAlt />&nbsp;&nbsp;<span className="text-muted">Filters</span></> }
    >
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="1">My Invoices</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="2">Draft</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="3">Posted</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="4">Cancelled</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="5">To Check</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="6">Unpaid</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="7">Paid</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="8">Overdue</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="9" as={ ButtonGroup }>
        <Dropdown>
            <Button variant="light">Invoice Date</Button>
            <Dropdown.Toggle split variant="light" id="dropdown-split-basic" />
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="12">Action</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="13">Another action</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item eventKey="14">Something else here</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    </Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="10">Due Date</Dropdown.Item>
    <Dropdown.Divider />
    <Dropdown.Item eventKey="11">Add Custom Filter</Dropdown.Item>
</DropdownButton>`
```

I have looked through the documentation [on split button dropdowns](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/) but there is no example of a `Dropdown.Item` being converted into this but I need this in my use case.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is working. It's just by default dropdown menu is closed when you click inside. You can change this behaviour by adjusting the property *autoClose*. In my example I set it to false:

https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-taussig-6nqj1k

- Manage the desired visibility behaviour with *show*, *onToggle* and *onSelect*.
- Style as needed